# Is there a way to find the correct element in the array for the given index x?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, quicksort

In quick sort, in each iteration we are able to find correct index for an element (i.e. pivot element).

Is there any algorithm to find correct element for a given index ?

Here, correct index of an element means the final index of the element which would appear after sorting the array.

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

Comment: Quick select fits the bill?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is exactly what a [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) does.  It can be done in linear time.

Comment: For a single index, can it be done in logarithmic time? For example, if we want to find the correct element at ith index, can it be found in logarithmic time ?

Comment: @CodeJack, no, it requires linear time.